# If $\mu$ is a compactly supported measure, does the Fourier inverse of $\widehat{\mu}$ exist and if so is it compactly supported?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has compact support. Then the Fourier transform $\widehat{\mu}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\, d\mu(x)$ is smooth. Does the Fourier inverse of $\widehat{\mu}$ necessarily exist? If it did exist, is it compactly supported?

Comment: See these notes http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/381/FourierTransforms.pdf

Comment: write that $\mu(A) = \int_A \nu(x)dx$ where  $\nu$ is a distribution (tempered since compactly supported), and you'll get that $\widehat{\mu}$ is the Fourier transform of $\nu$